# Not able to save firefox profile plugin activation changes using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When i am opening my same firefox profile through selenium webdriver, each time I have to activate shockwave player manually and changes are not getting saved in firefox profile.

Is there any way to activate plugins through script automatically or save changes in firefox profile for later use.

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Test-pc1\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("SeleniumTest"); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
myprofile.setPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.Shockwaveflash.exe", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you to achieve, what you want.

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/ You can refer this.
Once you created your FF profile then, launch it and click on Option menu in right top corner,Select Options.

[image]

Select Application, And select the application and say savefile

[image]

Once you done, it then run you test with this profile.As mention in the link above.

Comment: Thank you Sudha for the solution, but it did not work for me :(( Actually i am not able to find shockwave player plugin in applications content type

Comment: Is there any way to activate adobe shockwave player plugin through selenium webdriver script          
   myprofile.setPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.Shockwaveflash.exe", "true");

Comment: I have no clue about this now.But i will get back to you if i find any.